# How do I make arrows despawn faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here is some context: I've made some command block code to make lightning arrows. However, I want the arrows to instantaneously despawn after an arrow is shot. How do I do this?

Here is the command block code if you need it.

`execute at @e[type=minecraft:arrow] run summon minecraft:lightning_bolt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow] run data modify @s {Life:0}
```

This in another command block should instantly destroy every arrow. A similar command using `/kill` instead should also have the same effect.

Comment: yes, `/kill @e[type=minecraft:arrow]` should be equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `life` tag when summoning it.
The command would look like this:
`/summon arrow ~ ~ ~ {life:1100}`.
You may need to change the number to alter its lifespan.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the `summon` command? Or is that impossible?

Comment: alt x Perhaps you could make a mod

Comment: I think you've misunderstood his question. He wants to instantly kill arrows as soon as they are shot: "However, I want the arrows to instantaneously despawn after an arrow is shot"